# Can a t-test be used with data from several individuals?

Tags: t-test, mean, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, paired-data

I have turning data for animals in different conditions with comparisons of before and after these conditions, we'll say condA, condB.

Each animal has 3 repeats on both conditions, where before a treatment is compared to after a treatment (of the same condition). So condA before is compared to condA after, etc.

There are 3 ways I can think of doing this, I'm fairly sure it's number 3:

1. Can I just get all of the means of all of the individuals, then just have a paired t-test for all individuals with before and after condA? - This gives just one t-test for condA for all individuals
2. Or can I create means of the means of each individual, then do a unpaired t-test of all of the means of the means for before and after condA? - This gives just one t-test for condA for all individuals
3. Or does the data need to be separated into each individual, with each individual having its own t-test for condA before/after - I use a paired t-test to compare the 3 means of turning rate for before condA, to the 3 means for after condA of each individual? - This gives a p value per individual for condA before/after

So, which one should I use?

Thank you